# EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of RouterOutlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I try to add a landing page in Angular 2.

**// app.ts**

```
<div *ngIf="isSignedIn">
    <nav>
        <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Dashboard</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['About']">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isSignedIn">
    <landing-component></landing-component>
</div>
```

The weird thing is that it is working well when I first sign in.

But when I sign out and sign in again, it will show:

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of RouterOutlet!.
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot reuse an outlet that does not contain a component.

What does this error mean?

Or is there any other way to add a landing page? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think the problem in my question may be because when I sign out, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be gone. So when I use router to go to the landing component, it shows the error.

I changed to this structure, and now it is working.

```
<div>
   <nav *ngIf="isSignedIn">
      <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Dashboard</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['About']">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Use Router to go to landing component. And landing component has its own `<nav></nav>`. And landing component can have his own child router.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this plunker help you, has the same mistake you said

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hXAxOj73G5CrAPhV4hkJ?p=preview)</kbd>

```
@Component({
  selector: 'compLogin'
})
@View({
  template: `<div>CompLogin</div><button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>,
  directives: [RouterOutlet] 
})
```

but if you add in `selector: 'compLogin'` this ->`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'compLogin'
})
@View({
  template: `<div>CompLogin</div><button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [RouterOutlet] 
})
```

it works well.

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VppjRClkkWAhJp4JmITf?p=preview)</kbd>

sorry for my English and I hope you understand me.I hope it will help

---

https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.router/RouterOutlet/reuse.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, Angel! But I decided to change to another structure. Now it is working.